# Format json based on parent element type

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a JSON and I need everyone who is different from type 1 to have immediately below type 1 to become child of type 1

That is if it is different from 1 and just below type 1 this value must become a nested object of type 1

exemple

```
array = [
  {
    name: 'name1',
    type: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'name2',
    type: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'name3',
    type: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'name4',
    type: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'name5',
    type: 2
  },
]
```

The array should become something like this below.

```
arrayFormated = [
  {
    name: 'name1',
    type: 1
    child: [
      {
        name: 'name2',
        type: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'name3',
        type: 3
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    name: 'name4',
    type: 1,
    child: [{
      name: 'name5',
      type: 2
    }]
  },
]
```

i try use map

```
  this.formatedArray = array.map((x, index) => {
    if (x.type !== 1) {
      return {
        name: x.name
        type: x.type
      }
    }
```

Comment: Also post what you tried.

Comment: What you have posted is not JSON, it's an array literal.

Comment: @RobG what the difference ?

Comment: [JSON](http://www.json.org) is a string format used to transmit data, it's based on the notation for ECMAScript object literals and standardised as [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). An array literal is code that is valid ECMAScript syntax, but is not necessarily (and nearly always isn't) valid JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop to iterate on the array, and if an item's `type` is `1`, you can assign it to `parent`.

Then continue appending other elements to `children` array until an item with `type` of `1` is encountered again. Then add the children as a `child` property to `parent` object and push the result to a new array.

```js
let array = [{ name: 'name1', type: 1 }, { name: 'name2', type: 2 }, { name: 'name3', type: 3 }, { name: 'name4', type: 1 }, { name: 'name5', type: 2 }, ];

let result = [];
let parent = null;
let children = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i].type === 1) {
    if (parent) {
      parent.child = children;
      result.push(Object.assign(parent));
      children = [];
    }
    parent = Object.assign(array[i]);
    continue;
  }

  children.push(Object.assign(array[i]));
}

if (parent) {
  parent.child = children;
  result.push(Object.assign(parent));
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i can use it with the map ?

Comment: @user3140824—no. *map* makes a new array based on the return value from a supplied function, it gets messy quickly if you start modifying the array you're iterating over. You might use either *reduce* or *forEach* and either create a new array or modify the existing array (but again, modifying the array you're iterating over can get very messy).

Answer (score 1):

You can use various approaches for that. Most verbose would be to use loops, for example (not sure if it really works, didn't run it, treat is as pseudo code pls):

```js
const result = [];
let parent;
array.forEach(element => {
  if (element.type === 1) {
     parent = element;
     parent.children = [];
     result.push(element);

     return;
   }
   parent.children.push(element);
})
```

What concerns me most is that your question smells like there's something wrong with the task you're trying to do. I don't know the background because your post is very abstract, but I suspect you're trying to solve a problem that can be solved in a simpler way.

We, programmers often fix on first solution that comes to our head and hesitate to step back and re-think the whole problem again to find something more suitable if the solution doesn't really work or is fragile.

I hope I helped in any way.

Comment: the problem is that an API returns me like this and I need to do another way to list

Comment: A version using a *for* loop is 10 characters more than using *forEach*, so not really "verbose"

Comment: Oh, worth noting that this also modifies the original array in a probably unhelpful way.